# ¿Qué significa "problem-driven"?

Tags: java

Estoy leyendo un libro de programación de Java, y me encontré la palabra **"problem-driven"**. No sé cómo traducir correctamente esta frase en un contexto de programación, cabe destacar también que mi conocimiento en Java es muy básico, tal vez por eso no entiendo bien qué quiere decir esa oración.

¿Habrá alguna traducción exacta para esta palabra?

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir un fragmento del libro donde aparezca esa palabra, para ver el contexto?

Answer (score 1):

Encontré este fragmento en una página que describe el libro *[Introduction to Java Programming, Tenth Edition](http://www.cs.armstrong.edu/liang/intro10e/features.html)*:

> This book teaches problem solving in a problem-driven way that focuses on problem solving rather than syntax.

También hallé [este hilo](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/problem-driven.3041220/) en los foros de Wordreference.com, con la siguiente respuesta:

> Yo cuando es whatsit-driven en general salgo adelante con 'enfocar'.
>
> My attempt: Un marco de análisis de (la) economía política enfocado en (los) problemas.

No me parece que haya una traducción específica en el contexto de programación; yo diría que esa palabra simplemente se traduce como **enfocado(a) en los problemas**.